# Automated Silverlight Unit Testing with CruiseControl.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, unit-testing, cruisecontrol.net

What is currently the best solution to automate running unit tests against silverlight applications within CruiseControl.NET?

Preferably I would like to run MSTest unit tests however as these aren't officially supported for silverlight yet I am open to suggestions that use other testing frameworks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The November version of the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) contains not only the Silverlight Unit Testing Framework, but also an MSBuild task to allow the framework to be run from the command line. See [Jeff Wilcox's post](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/11/november-walkthrough/) for detail, but you essentially end up doing this:

```
msbuild /t:test /p:browser=firefox
```

As CC.Net can run MSBuild you should be able to at least call the tests. The output is in TRX format.

I've used this framework with some success, although not integrated into CC.Net, it works fine but the tests run in a browser so are a little slow. The advantage of running in the browser is you can do more acceptance-like tests, running up controls to display. The framework also includes methods to cope with the asynchronous nature of Silverlight.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Nice!

Comment: This is nice indeed. Does this make the tests fully automateable on an unattended build server? Eg the browser should close itself after the test have run and the output saved

Comment: @jbloomer: Do you have experience with using the testing framework provided in the November toolkit? It appears the Silverlight Test Project template doesn't install in VS2008. Is it a VS2010 template onle?

Comment: There's two different downloads on the Codeplex page. 

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=36060#ReleaseFiles

One for 4 and one for 3. I would guess that the 4 version is VS2010 only? But haven't tried it.

Also haven't got it plumbed into CC.Net yet, I assumed it would close the browser.

Answer (score 3):

I've been having this issue and at the moment there's *no official supported* way of doing these unit tests. The main problem is that the Silverlight Unit Testing Framework does not support plugging into MSTest and therefore can't really be integrated into any CI. However there is a way to hack around this using Powerhell - see [here](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2292).

I personally see that it's *quite a hassle* to get these tests plugged into CI and for the time being run them only on my local machine.

*Update:* as jbloomer wrote, there is a *walkthrough available* [on Jeff Wilcox's blog](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/11/november-walkthrough/) on how to set up an MSBuild task for the Silverlight Unit Testing Framework. I would recommend choosing this path: once MSBuild is set up, you should have no problem plugging it into CruiseControl.NET.

Answer (score 2):

For running Silverlight Unit Tests from command line in CCNet or TeamCity you can use Lighthouse Silverlight Unit Test Runner:

http://lighthouse.codeplex.com/

It works with any build server because it runs unit tests and produces NUnit compatible xml results file so you run it the same way like running NUnit Console runner.

Comment: This also works great with Jenkins CI. The test results are picked up seamlessly by the NUnit plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a third party testing framework like NUnit or XUnit.net?  You could then call the executable from within CC.net.  In fact, CCNet has an NUnit task.

Comment: Neither NUnit nor XUnit support Silverlight specific tests.

Answer (score 0):

Along with [LightHouse](http://lighthouse.codeplex.com/) there is another testing automation tool - [StatLight](http://statlight.codeplex.com).